# Why is sqrt() not a method on Numeric?

Tags: ruby, oop

In Ruby everything is an object. That's why I don't understand why we have the Math module. It seems to me that most (all?) of the functions in the Math module should have been methods on the numeric types like Integer, Float and so on.

E.g. instead of

```
Math.sqrt(5)
```

it would make more sense to have

```
5.sqrt
```

The same goes for `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `log10` and so on.

Does anyone know why all these functions ended up in the Math module?

Comment: `5.sqrt` is waaay tooo backwards

Comment: Kaptajn, because that's TOO OOP IMO, and is too weird for programmers migrating from other languages

Comment: #abs is a method though: -6.abs #=> 6

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know the early history of Ruby, but I have a feeling the Math module was modelled after the C <math.h> header. It is an odd duck in the Ruby standard library though.

But, it's Ruby! So you can always bust out the monkey patching!

```
class Float
  def sqrt; Math.sqrt(self); end
  def sin; Math.sin(self); end
  def cos; Math.cos(self); end
  def tan; Math.tan(self); end
  def log10; Math.log10(self); end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

To expand on [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844526/why-is-sqrt-not-a-method-on-float/2844568#2844568), there's no need to define all those methods by hand.  Note that I explicitly skip the two Math methods that take two arguments.

```
class Numeric
  (Math.methods - Module.methods - ["hypot", "ldexp"]).each do |method|
    define_method method do
      Math.send method, self
    end
  end
end

puts 25.sqrt
puts 100.log10
```

Output:

```
5.0
2.0
```

In regards to exactly why those methods are not included in `Numeric` already, I'm really not sure of a good reason.  I don't think namespace pollution as [Andrew mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844526/why-is-sqrt-not-a-method-on-float/2845817#2845817) is particularly a risk in the `Numeric` class; Michael is probably on the right track with historic carryover.

Comment: Change that to `define_method(method) do |*args| Math.send(method, self, *args) end`, and there's no longer a need to exclude `hypot` or `ldexp`.

Comment: The expression (Math.methods - Module.methods) can also be shortened to just Math.methods(false)

Comment: Combined for convenience into a one-liner (in class Numeric): `Math.methods(false).each {|m| define_method m do |*args| Math.send m, self, *args end }`

Answer (score 8):

I've rewritten Mark's answer to be more concise, and not require removing `hypot` and `ldexp`, since I'm using this approach myself.

```
class Numeric
  Math.methods(false).each do |method|
    define_method method do |*args|
      Math.send(method, self, *args)
    end
  end
end

>> 3.hypot(4)
=> 5.0

>> Math::PI.sqrt
=> 1.7724538509055159

>> 10.log10
=> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

When talking about modules and namespaces, Programming Ruby (the pickaxe) gave an example of an object with both mathematical functions mixed in, and functions to do with morality mixed in, so that it could calculate [how many angels can dance on the head of a pin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_many_angels_can_dance_on_the_head_of_a_pin%3F). It then noted that without proper namespacing, `sin` could be an ambiguous term.

So maybe it's about namespace pollution.

Comment: That concern applies to duck typing in general, not just the Math functions. I doubt that could be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

`5 ** 0.5` demonstrates that ruby's exponentiation operator can handle square roots directly, as for log, sin etc, these make more sense to me as global functions rather than methods: their origins are in mathematics and are not closely related to any one float instance.